# Mount SMB error 22 and error 2

Tags: networking, mount, samba, cifs

I am trying to mount an SMB share onto /mnt/local_share. I am able to view the drive in Nautilus and when I type CTRL-L I get the directory:

smb://share_name;user@email.edu/lab_name

The drive is connected via ethernet and using `ip a` I found the IP address was 10.139.xx.xxx

So I tried mounting by doing:

`$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user //10.139.xx.xxx/ /mnt/local_share/`

But I got an error about not being able to connect to the network (sorry forgot to copy it)

Next I did

`$ ping share_name`

Which successfully connected and returned an IP address of 10.76.y.yy

So then I have tried a variety of mount cifs options. Each time I have been prompted to enter my user@share_name password

`$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user //share_name/lab_name /mnt/local_share/`

mount error(2): No such file or directory

`$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user //share_name /mnt/local_share/`

mount error(2): No such file or directory

`$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user //10.76.y.yy/lab_name /mnt/local_share/`

mount error(2): No such file or directory

`$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user@email.edu/lab_name //share_name /mnt/local_share/`

mount error(22): Invalid argument

`$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user //10.76.y.yy /mnt/local_share/`

mount error(22): Invalid argument

`$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user@email.edu //share_name /mnt/local_share/`

mount error(22): Invalid argument

Any ideas? I'm not familiar with this smb://share_name;user@email.edu/lab_name format in previous SMB systems.